# Rebuilding Indexes in SDE Database throws "Could not get a lock." error

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase

While trying to do some maintenance on our SDE database but i am always getting a "Could not get a lock." error on the details section of the process.

Do i need to setup something for me to successfully run the index rebuilding tool?

Btw, i am using ArcMap 10.1 to rebuild the indexes.

Thanks.

Comment: If you right-click on your SDE GDB in Catalog > Administration > Administer Geodatabase.. you will find the Connections and Locks tabs which may help you identify where the locks are coming from.

Comment: hi amarinel, i did see a lot of locks from the method that you have advised but unfortunately, i can't test it now. I'll wait until the weekend to test this. I would just disconnect the users and proceed with the rebuilding of indexes right?

Comment: This is certainly possible.  If you wait until off-peak times when there are less users then this is advantageous.  I have seen the scenario where I have ArcGIS for Server using data in the GDB (i.e. using it in a published map service) and I cannot use the tool to end the connection in Catalog.  In this case, you have to stop the map service manually in ArcGIS Server and the locks disappear.  If you use Server, consider this.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that SDE gets some hung locks from time to time.
If you run a compress, this will terminate any of these hung locks and may give you some success.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click the database that you connected to;
2. Choose "Administration"-> "Administer Geodatabase";
3. Select the "Connections" tab, then right click the items and close
   them;
4. You can re-build indexes when there was only one item that
   connected by yourself.

[image]

[image]